# Answer converted to comment by admin

Tags: discussion, answers, closed-questions

I had an answer converted to a comment on:  https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/5775/health-commute-skills-and-money
The question was closed and I doubt it will be reworded to be appropriate for this site, but if it is, will my comment get converted back to an answer? I do believe I answered the question. Maybe some feedback on my answer would have helped?

I'm not sure this benefits the site. Closing the question should be enough.

Comment: I agree that I'm not sure it really matters one way or another, but your answer does strike me as a comment.  You are asking several questions back to the asker, with not much substance (and not backed up as enderland pointed out).

Answer (score 6):

How does your comment answer the question?

You basically restated things the asker already said.

Regardless, from the FAQ:

> Make sure your answer adds helpful information and is a complete,
>   stand-alone answer. Read other answers first and be sure not to
>   completely restate information that has already been posted.
>
> Please note that answers should be backed up either with a reference,
>   or experiences that happened to you personally. You should always
>   include in your answer information about why you think your answer is
>   correct.

Your comment doesn't really do either of those paragraphs (though, to be fair, it doesn't really *say* much to be backed up, so perhaps the second part is not so applicable?).

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think it's moot.  I voted to delete the question because the case is very specific to the asker, and very much a personal choice that will be subject to debate.

But to give feedback, I'd say the indication that this isn't an answer as much as a comment is that you ask two very meaningful questions in the course of giving the answer (is this a livable wage? can you telecommute?) - if this was a conversation between two people, you would certainly providing helpful and meaningful input for the question asker - in my dream world for this as a conversation, he'd answer, you'd provide more thoughts, and he'd find an answer to his problem.

The problem is, this a Q&A site, not a conversation.  You can certainly ask for this kind of clarification in comments - but the answer should be solid enough that *any* person with the same question could get value out of your answer.  As it is, they'd have to write you, answer your questions, get your feedback and then have an answer - it doesn't fit the format of the site.

Being fair, I don't think you're the problem - this started as a very personal "what should I do with my job?" question, and it wasn't a good fit in the first place, so it's hardly surprising that the answer you could provide was also not a good fit.

Thanks for trying, though.